# Receiving Gzipped POST requests

Tags: php, post, gzip

I'm sending POST requests to a page that as the following code :

> $post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
>
> $text=$post['text'];
>
> echo gettype($text);
>
> echo $text;

When i'm sending strings under 260 or so bytes, it works fine. But for higher sizes, it just prints NULL. I believe that strings >260b get automatically gzipped with the software I use. How can I retrieve the data I want ?

PS : I'm really new to php

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$_POST['text'];
```

instead of:

```
post['text'];
```

---

Edit: misread question, can you try this:

```
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));
```

and post the output here so we know what the return looks like?

Comment: Output : array(1) {
  ["text"]=>
  string(35) "the text is here<br>with a new line"
}
NULL

Comment: And for big strings : I just get NULL
NULL

Comment: I get 'Call to undefined function  json_last_error()'

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? PHP4.x ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56583/discussion-between-hippalectryon-and-joran-den-houting).